# Installing OpenSSL 1.0.1c on OSX

Tags: macos, openssl, installation

I downloaded OpenSSL 1.0.1c and ran this

```
sudo ./config --prefix=/usr/
make
make test
sudo make install
```

All seems well, no errors, but then:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
```

`OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT` has the same problem. It's an old version! And oddly, a different old version (0.9.8r). Not using `--prefix=/usr/` gives the same problem. How do I update to 1.0.1c? I need to be able to use it for testing a library I'm making.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not install it use `homebrew` or `macports`?
My openssl version is `1.0.1c`,I think I installed it using macports as a dependency of an other package.

```
☁  ~  openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I link to it? I've tried macports but I don't know how to link my program to the macports version...

Comment: 1.`cd /usr/bin;sudo mv openssl openssl.bak`;2.`sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/openssl openssl`;3.`openssl version`

Comment: Macports works. It took a while since it was playing up but I got it working. I use /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib for the search paths and it works. :-)